# Why is a random component needed for ECDH key pair generation in Mbed TLS?

Tags: elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman

Please forgive me if this is not the right place, however, I encountered [this](https://tls.mbed.org/api/ecdh_8h.html#a403a5d7363b6219a2017b837b665c354) TLS implementation with a function that generates an ECDH key pair on an elliptic curve:

In addition to the private key and a point on the curve, the function also needs random inputs. Why and for what are the random variables required? Why isn't it just $Q=[d]G$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is used to implement countermeasures against side-channel attacks.

From the paper:

> If f_rng is not NULL, it is used to implement countermeasures against side-channel attacks.

And

> The RNG function, for blinding purposes. This may b(sic) NULL if blinding isn't needed.

See more in [mbed API Documentation](https://tls.mbed.org/api/ecp_8h.html#a4d005045c302e100c78bdc587e8f0e6a).

---

The modular inverse operation as implemented in Mbed TLS was previously vulnerable to a single-trace side channel attack. This allowed an attacker with access to precise enough timing and memory access information (typically an untrusted operating system attacking a secure enclave such as SGX or the TrustZone secure world) to fully recover an ECDSA private key after observing a number of signature operations.

To combat these sorts of attacks, we can employ blinding; we include random data in our computations, and while the end results is independent of the random value, the intermediate values are strongly dependent, and thus the correlations between the intermediate states and anything that the attacker wants (such as the private key) is much weaker.

For further information on blinding, see

- [Scalar Blinding on Elliptic Curves with Special
  Structure](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/801.pdf) by Scott Fluhrer. Section 2 specifically discusses and references various techniques.

The specific attack on Mbed TLS is detailed further in this paper,

- [From A to Z: Projective coordinates leakage in the wild](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/432.pdf) by Aldaya et. al, in 2020.

as taken from the mbed security update

- [Side channel attack on ECDSA](https://tls.mbed.org/tech-updates/security-advisories/mbedtls-security-advisory-2020-04) .

There is a somewhat related follow-up from the same authors

- [Side-channel attack on ECC key import and validation](https://tls.mbed.org/tech-updates/security-advisories/mbedtls-security-advisory-2020-07)

---

Note [PolarSSL was acquired by ARM Holdings in 2014](https://polarssl.org/tech-updates/blog/polarssl-part-of-arm) and As of the release of version 1.3.10, PolarSSL has been [rebranded to Mbed TLS](http://community.arm.com/groups/internet-of-things/blog/2015/02/09/polarssl-is-dead-long-live-mbed-tls).

Comment: Thanks. If ECDH is used against a server that is using the same private key, the shared secret is always the same. There is no random argument in the shared secret calculation?

Comment: I can't code C or whatever that is so can't make head nor tail of it!  If it's running as a dummy operation then it could be worded clearer.  It states the PRNG runs the exact same sequence for any valid 'm'.

Comment: See my update with the attack paper/security update that goes into more detail. Especially section 4 of the paper.